# "Application-defined or object-defined error" when entering a formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to enter a formula into cells using VBA, but on the second line of the following code I get an error:

> "Application-Defined or Object-defined"

Is there something I am entering wrong?

```
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(Prepared Screens'!A:A)"
Range("D5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(Senior Reviewed'!A:A)"
Range("D6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTA(Manager Reviewed'!A:A)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening `'` tick when enclosing the worksheet name.

```
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('Prepared Screens'!A:A)"
Range("D5").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('Senior Reviewed'!A:A)"
Range("D6").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('Manager Reviewed'!A:A)"
```

You don't need to Select a cell to assign a formula.

```
Range("D4").Formula = "=COUNTA('Prepared Screens'!A:A)"
Range("D5").Formula = "=COUNTA('Senior Reviewed'!A:A)"
Range("D6").Formula = "=COUNTA('Manager Reviewed'!A:A)"
```

Answer (score 0):

A single quote is missing from each of the rows setting the Formul, and you should use `.Formula` instead of `.FormulaR1C1` if you refer to the range this way. Try this:

```
Range("D4").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('Prepared Screens'!A:A)"
Range("D5").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('Senior Reviewed'!A:A)"
Range("D6").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=COUNTA('Manager Reviewed'!A:A)"
```

Comment: Thank you! What is the difference between .Formula and .FormulaR1C1?

Comment: Try that you write in the Immediate Window: Range("A1").Formula = "B1". And print what Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 is. It will be RC[1]. In this R means same row, and C[1] means one column to the right.